# iOS iPad and iPhone user agent does not work in Phonegap application

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I´m trying to detect if the device is an iPad or an iPhone, but it isn´t working with the emulator. It works if i test it in the safari browser on the iPad. Is there a difference?
It always uses the "else" for iphone..

this i my code:

```
var isiPad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;

$(document).ready(function(){
if(isiPad)
{
window.location.replace("tab/indexTabStart.html");
}
else {
window.location.replace("smart/indexSmartStart.html");

}
});
```

please help me thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the api provided by phonegap.
try using `device.model`

`device.model - Get the device's model name.`

example:

`var string = device.model;`

Description

`The device.model returns the name of the device's model or product. The value is set by the device manufacturer and may be different across versions of the same product.`

for full documentation here:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#Device